# No sasl auth mechanism available

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, dovecot, sasl

I'm trying to use Dovecot+Postfix+Mysql so far everything worked fine. Since upgrading from Debian 6 to 7 I'm unable to send mails. Receiving is still possible.

/var/log/mail.log

```
Oct 22 15:21:24 XXXXXXXX postfix/smtpd[17765]: warning: XXXXX: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
```

I tried to research for the error and found a couple of things, which did not realy help so far.

This is my output for postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 30720000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = mail.XXXX.com, mail.XXXX.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = XXXX.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
```

and my dovecot.conf

```
protocols = imap pop3
listen = *
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir

ssl_cert =</etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key =</etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem

namespace {
    type=private
    separator = .
    prefix = INBOX.
    inbox = yes
}

protocol lda {
    log_path = /home/vmail/dovecot-deliver.log
    auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
    postmaster_address = postmaster@XXXX.com
    mail_plugins = sieve
}

plugin {
    sieve_global_path = /home/vmail/globalsieverc
}

protocol pop3 {
    pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}

service auth {
    user = root
}

passdb {
        driver = sql
        args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}

userdb {
        driver = static
        args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/home/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
}

service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
  unix_listener auth-master {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
```

The only changes I made after the upgrade where adapting the dovecot.conf to work with the newer version of dovecot, which has been installed. I assume that something in the section service auth is wrong, but could not find what still after a lot of googling.

Can you provide any further help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've told dovecot to set up this service for auth:

'unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth '

Where have you told postfix to talk to that socket?

Comment: Thank you very much!
Somehow
    `smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot`
    `smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth`
was missing. I cannot understand why it worked before the upgrade.